# Working out the details of a type indexed free monad

Tags: haskell, dsl

I've been using a free monad to build a DSL. As part of the language, there is an `input` command, the goal is to reflect what types are expected by the input primitive at the type level for additional safety.

For example, I want to be able to write the following program.

```
concat :: Action '[String, String] ()
concat = do
  (x :: String) <- input
  (y :: String) <- input 
  output $ x ++ " " ++ y
```

Along with an evaluation function

```
eval :: Action params res -> HList params -> [String]
eval = ...
```

Which works in the following way..

```
> eval concat ("a" `HCons` "b" `HCons` HNil)
["a b"]
```

Here's what I have so far.

```
data HList i where
  HNil :: HList '[]
  HCons :: h -> HList t -> HList (h ': t)

type family Append (a :: [k]) (b :: [k]) :: [k] where
  Append ('[]) l = l
  Append (e ': l) l' = e ': (Append l l')

data ActionF next where
   Input :: (a -> next) ->  ActionF next
   Output :: String -> next -> ActionF next

instance Functor ActionF where
  fmap f (Input c) = Input (fmap f c)
  fmap f (Output s n) = Output s (f n)

data FreeIx f i a where
  Return :: a -> FreeIx f '[] a
  Free :: f (FreeIx f i a) -> FreeIx f i a

type Action i a = FreeIx ActionF i a

liftF :: Functor f => f a -> FreeIx f i a
liftF = Free . fmap Return

input :: forall a . Action '[a] a
input = liftF (Input id)

output :: String -> Action '[] ()
output s = liftF (Output s ())

bind :: Functor f => FreeIx f t a -> (a -> FreeIx f v b) -> FreeIx f (Append t v) b
bind (Return a) f = f a
bind (Free x) f   = Free (fmap (flip bind f) x)
```

The problem is that `liftF` does not type check.

```
liftF :: Functor f => Proxy i -> f a -> FreeIx f i a
liftF p = Free . fmap Return
```

Is this the correct approach?

I thought some inspiration might come from the [effect monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/effect-monad) package. This is what led to the definition of `Return` and `Free`.

For some more backstory: I've seen in several places that users will define DSLs in this way and then define an evaluation function `eval :: Action a -> [String] -> a` or something similar. The clear problem with this approach is that all arguments must have the same type and there is no static guarantee that the correct number of arguments will be supplied. This is an attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: For me `liftF` doesn't check either on GHC 7.8.3

Comment: Upon more reflection, it also appears that writing `eval` is non-trivial.

Comment: There's something important missing from this question - it has to do with why you included a definition for `HList`. You are trying to build something that reads from the `HList`, with a proof that it reads the types one-for-one in order.

Comment: You could edit the post to illustrate the property @Cirdec pointed out by changing `addTwo` to something non-associative like `concatTwo`, with `show x ++ " " ++ show y`, and adding a note that `eval concatTwo (HCons 1 $ HCons 2 $ HNil)` would output `"1 2"`.

Comment: I have changed the question to remove some unnecessary cruft and add the example Christian suggested.

Comment: I'm one type-level proof away from a solid answer. I need to prove to the compiler that `Append` is associative. Specifically, I need to prove that `Append i1 j1 ~ i` implies `Append i1 (Append j1 j) ~ Append i j`. The only reference I can find for this is https://gist.github.com/jasonreich/756130 which requires the Stathclyde Haskell Enhancement.

Comment: @Cirdec does [this one](https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/c45c0e005013dc468c76) help?

Comment: @AndrásKovács Very much, I have incorporated that into a [comprehensive answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27682570/414413).

Comment: Looks like there was already a package for this. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/indexed-free

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have found a satisfactory solution to this problem. Here's a sneak peek at the ultimate result:

```
addTwo = do
  (x :: Int) <- input
  (y :: Int) <- input 
  output $ show (x + y)

eval (1 ::: 2 ::: HNil) addTwo = ["3"]
```

Accomplishing this requires a large number of steps. First, we need to observe that the `ActionF` data type is itself indexed. We will adapt `FreeIx` to build an indexed monad using the free monoid, lists. The `Free` constructor for `FreeIx` will need to capture a witness to the finiteness of one of its two indexes for use in proofs. We will use a [system due to András Kovács for writing proofs about appending type level lists](https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/c45c0e005013dc468c76) to make proofs of both associativity and the right identity. We will [describe indexed monads in the same manner as Oleg Grenrus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27678650/414413). We will use the `RebindbableSyntax` extension to write expressions for an `IxMonad` using the ordinary `do` notation.

#### Prologue

In addition to all of the extensions your example already requires and `RebindbableSyntax` which was mentioned above we will also need `UndecidableInstances` for the trivial purpose of reusing a type family definition.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}
```

We will be using the [`:~:` GADT from `Data.Type.Equality`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html) to manipulate type equality.

```
import Data.Type.Equality
import Data.Proxy
```

Because we will be rebinding the `Monad` syntax, we'll hide all of `Monad` from the `Prelude` import. The `RebindableSyntax` extension uses for `do` notation whatever functions `>>=`, `>>`, and `fail` are in scope.

```
import Prelude hiding (Monad, (>>=), (>>), fail, return)
```

We also have a few bits of new general-purpose library code. I have given the `HList` an infix constructor, `:::`.

```
data HList i where
  HNil :: HList '[]
  (:::) :: h -> HList t -> HList (h ': t)

infixr 5 :::
```

I have renamed the `Append` type family `++` to mirror the `++` operator on lists.

```
type family (++) (a :: [k]) (b :: [k]) :: [k] where
  '[]      ++ l  = l
  (e ': l) ++ l' = e ': l ++ l'
```

It's useful to talk about constraints of the form `forall i. Functor (f i)`. These don't exist in `Haskell` outside GADTs that capture constraints like [the `Dict` GADT in constraints](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.4.1.1/docs/Data-Constraint.html). For our purposes, it will be sufficient to define a version of `Functor` with an extra ignored argument.

```
class Functor1 (f :: k -> * -> *) where
    fmap1 :: (a -> b) -> f i a -> f i b
```

#### Indexed ActionF

The `ActionF` `Functor` was missing something, it had no way to capture type level information about the requirements of the methods. We'll add an additional index type `i` to capture this. `Input` requires a single type, `'[a]`, while `Output` requires no types, `'[]`. We are going to call this new type parameter the index of the functor.

```
data ActionF i next where
   Input :: (a -> next) ->  ActionF '[a] next
   Output :: String -> next -> ActionF '[] next
```

We'll write `Functor` and `Functor1` instances for `ActionF`.

```
instance Functor (ActionF i) where
  fmap f (Input c) = Input (fmap f c)
  fmap f (Output s n) = Output s (f n)

instance Functor1 ActionF where
  fmap1 f = fmap f
```

#### FreeIx Reconstructed

We are going to make two changes to `FreeIx`. We will change how the indexes are constructed. The `Free` constructor will refer to the index from the underlying functor, and produce a `FreeIx` with an index that's the free monoidal sum (`++`) of the index from the underlying functor and the index from the wrapped `FreeIx`. We will also require that `Free` captures a witness to a proof that the index of the underlying functor is finite.

```
data FreeIx f (i :: [k]) a where
  Return :: a -> FreeIx f '[] a
  Free :: (WitnessList i) => f i (FreeIx f j a) -> FreeIx f (i ++ j) a
```

We can define `Functor` and `Functor1` instances for `FreeIx`.

```
instance (Functor1 f) => Functor (FreeIx f i) where
  fmap f (Return a) = Return (f a)
  fmap f (Free x) = Free (fmap1 (fmap f) x)

instance (Functor1 f) => Functor1 (FreeIx f) where
  fmap1 f = fmap f
```

If we want to use `FreeIx` with an ordinary, unindexed functor, we can lift those values to an unconstrained indexed functor, `IxIdentityT`. This isn't needed for this answer.

```
data IxIdentityT f i a = IxIdentityT {runIxIdentityT :: f a}

instance Functor f => Functor (IxIdentityT f i) where
    fmap f = IxIdentityT . fmap f . runIxIdentityT

instance Functor f => Functor1 (IxIdentityT f) where
    fmap1 f = fmap f
```

#### Proofs

We will need to prove two properties about appending type level lists. In order to write `liftF` we will need to prove the right identity `xs ++ '[] ~ xs`. We'll call this proof `appRightId` for append right identity. In order to write `bind` we will need to prove associativity `xs ++ (yz ++ zs) ~ (xs ++ ys) ++ zs`, which we will call `appAssoc`.

The proofs are written in terms of a successor list which is essentially a list of proxies, one for each type `type SList xs ~ HFMap Proxy (HList xs)`.

```
data SList (i :: [k]) where
  SNil :: SList '[]
  SSucc :: SList t -> SList (h ': t)
```

The following proof of associativity along with the method of writing this proof are 
[due to András Kovács](https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/c45c0e005013dc468c76). By only using `SList` for the type list of `xs` we deconstruct and using `Proxy`s for the other type lists, we can delay (possibly indefinitely) needing `WitnessList` instances for `ys` and `zs`.

```
appAssoc ::
  SList xs -> Proxy ys -> Proxy zs ->
  (xs ++ (ys ++ zs)) :~: ((xs ++ ys) ++ zs)
appAssoc SNil ys zs = Refl
appAssoc (SSucc xs) ys zs =
  case appAssoc xs ys zs of Refl -> Refl
```

`Refl`, the constructor for `:~:`, can only be constructed when the compiler is in possession of a proof that the two types are equal. Pattern matching on `Refl` introduces the proof of type equality into the current scope.

We can prove the right identity in a similar fashion

```
appRightId :: SList xs -> xs :~: (xs ++ '[])
appRightId SNil = Refl
appRightId (SSucc xs) = case appRightId xs of Refl -> Refl
```

To use these proofs we construct witness lists for the the class of finite type lists.

```
class WitnessList (xs :: [k]) where
  witness :: SList xs

instance WitnessList '[] where
  witness = SNil

instance WitnessList xs => WitnessList (x ': xs) where
  witness = SSucc witness
```

#### Lifting

Equipped with `appRightId` we can define lifting values from the underlying functor into `FreeIx`.

```
liftF :: forall f i a . (WitnessList i, Functor1 f) => f i a -> FreeIx f i a
liftF = case appRightId (witness :: SList i) of Refl -> Free . fmap1 Return
```

The explicit `forall` is for `ScopedTypeVariables`. The witness to the finiteness of the index, `WitnessList i`, is required by both the `Free` constructor and `appRightId`. The proof of `appRightId` is used to convince the compiler that the `FreeIx f (i ++ '[]) a` constructed is of the same type as `FreeIx f i a`. That `'[]` came from the `Return` that was wrapped in the underlying functor.

Our two commands, `input` and `output`, are written in terms of `liftF`.

```
type Action i a = FreeIx ActionF i a

input :: Action '[a] a
input = liftF (Input id)

output :: String -> Action '[] ()
output s = liftF (Output s ())
```

#### IxMonad and Binding

To use `RebindableSyntax` we'll define an `IxMonad` class with the same function names `(>>=)`, `(>>)`, and `fail` as `Monad` but different types. This class is described in [Oleg Grenrus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27678650/414413).

```
class Functor1 m => IxMonad (m :: k -> * -> *) where
    type Unit :: k
    type Plus (i :: k) (j :: k) :: k

    return :: a -> m Unit a
    (>>=) :: m i a -> (a -> m j b) -> m (Plus i j) b

    (>>) :: m i a -> m j b -> m (Plus i j) b
    a >> b = a >>= const b

    fail :: String -> m i a
    fail s = error s
```

Implementing `bind` for `FreeIx` requires the proof of associativity, `appAssoc`. The only `WitnessList` instance in scope, `WitnessList i`, is the one captured by the deconstructed `Free` constructor. Once again, the explicit `forall` is for `ScopedTypeVariables`.

```
bind :: forall f i j a b. (Functor1 f) => FreeIx f i a -> (a -> FreeIx f j b) -> FreeIx f (i ++ j) b
bind (Return a) f = f a
bind (Free (x :: f i1 (FreeIx f j1 a))) f =
    case appAssoc (witness :: SList i1) (Proxy :: Proxy j1) (Proxy :: Proxy j)
    of Refl -> Free (fmap1 (`bind` f) x)
```

`bind` is the only interesting part of the `IxMonad` instance for `FreeIx`.

```
instance (Functor1 f) => IxMonad (FreeIx f) where
    type Unit = '[]
    type Plus i j = i ++ j

    return = Return
    (>>=) = bind
```

#### We're done

All of the hard part is done. We can write a simple interpreter for `Action xs ()` in the most straight forward fashion. The only trick required is to avoid pattern matching on the `HList` constructor `:::` until after the type list `i` is known to be non-empty because we already matched on `Input`.

```
eval :: HList i -> Action i () -> [String]
eval inputs action = 
    case action of 
        Return () -> []
        Free (Input f) -> 
            case inputs of
                (x ::: xs) -> eval xs (f x)
        Free (Output s next) -> s : eval inputs next
```

If you are curious about the inferred type of `addTwo`

```
addTwo = do
  (x :: Int) <- input
  (y :: Int) <- input 
  output $ show (x + y)
```

it is

```
> :t addTwo
addTwo :: FreeIx ActionF '[Int, Int] ()
```

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thanks for taking the time to put it all together. There was one iteration where I had an index on `Action` as well.. turns out that's what was needed all along.

Comment: Nice! I note though that I got stuck with `FreeIx` because I wanted to make it generic in the index monoid (and I'm still thinking about how to do that).

Comment: I had indexed functor &rarr; indexed monad approach in mind, but didn't realised it is that complicated. Cool, you had time to go thru the trouble!

Comment: I posted an answer with an alternative solution, if you're interested.

Comment: @Cirdec Hi! I'd like to use a Set instead of the List, but I'm not quite sure how it should be done. Can you help please? I've made a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47485615/proof-of-associativity-law-for-type-level-set) for this

Answer (score 12):

I have a new solution that is simple and quite generally applicable.

So far in the thread we've used monads indexed by a monoid, but here I rely on the other popular notion of an indexed monad, the one that has typestate transitions (Hoare logic-style):

```
    return :: a -> m i i a
    (>>=) :: m i j a -> (a -> m j k b) -> m i k b
```

I believe the two approaches are equivalent (at least in theory), since we get the Hoare monad by indexing with the endomorphism monoid, and we can also go in the opposite direction by CPS encoding the monoidal appends in the state transitions. In practice, Haskell's type-level and kind-level language is rather weak, so moving back-and-forth between the two representations is not an option.

There is a problem though with the above type for `>>=`: it implies that we must compute the typestate in a top-down order, i. e. it forces the following definition for `IxFree`:

```
data IxFree f i j a where
  Pure :: a -> IxFree f i i a
  Free :: f i j (IxFree f j k a) -> IxFree f i k a
```

So, if we have a `Free exp` expression, then we first transition from `i` to `j` following the constructor of `exp`, and then get from `j` to `k` by checking the subexperssions of `exp`. This means that if we try to accumulate the `input` types in a list, we end up with a reversed list:

```
-- compute transitions top-down
test = do
  (x :: Int) <- input       -- prepend Int to typestate
  (y :: String) <- input    -- prepend String to typestate
  return ()                 -- do nothing
```

If we instead appended the types to the end of the list, the order would be right. But making that work in Haskell (especially making `eval` work) would require a gruelling amount of proof-writing, if it's even possible.

Let's compute the typestate bottom-up instead. It makes all kinds of computations where we build up some data structure depending on the syntax tree much more natural, and in particular it makes our job very easy here.

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    RebindableSyntax, DataKinds,
    GADTs, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators,
    PolyKinds, StandaloneDeriving, DeriveFunctor #-}

import Prelude hiding (Monad(..))

class IxFunctor (f :: ix -> ix -> * -> *) where
    imap :: (a -> b) -> f i j a -> f i j b

class IxFunctor m => IxMonad (m :: ix -> ix -> * -> *) where
    return :: a -> m i i a
    (>>=) :: m j k a -> (a -> m i j b) -> m i k b -- note the change of index orders

    (>>) :: m j k a -> m i j b -> m i k b -- here too
    a >> b = a >>= const b

    fail :: String -> m i j a
    fail = error

data IxFree f i j a where
  Pure :: a -> IxFree f i i a
  Free :: f j k (IxFree f i j a) -> IxFree f i k a -- compute bottom-up

instance IxFunctor f => Functor (IxFree f i j) where
  fmap f (Pure a)  = Pure (f a)
  fmap f (Free fa) = Free (imap (fmap f) fa)

instance IxFunctor f => IxFunctor (IxFree f) where
  imap = fmap

instance IxFunctor f => IxMonad (IxFree f) where
  return = Pure
  Pure a  >>= f = f a
  Free fa >>= f = Free (imap (>>= f) fa)

liftf :: IxFunctor f => f i j a -> IxFree f i j a
liftf = Free . imap Pure
```

Now implementing `Action` becomes simple.

```
data ActionF i j next where
  Input  :: (a -> next) -> ActionF i (a ': i) next
  Output :: String -> next -> ActionF i i next

deriving instance Functor (ActionF i j)                                      
instance IxFunctor ActionF where
  imap = fmap

type family (++) xs ys where -- I use (++) here only for the type synonyms
  '[] ++ ys = ys
  (x ': xs) ++ ys = x ': (xs ++ ys)

type Action' xs rest = IxFree ActionF rest (xs ++ rest)
type Action xs a = forall rest. IxFree ActionF rest (xs ++ rest) a  

input :: Action '[a] a
input = liftf (Input id)

output :: String -> Action '[] ()
output s = liftf (Output s ())

data HList i where
  HNil :: HList '[]
  (:::) :: h -> HList t -> HList (h ': t)
infixr 5 :::

eval :: Action' xs r a -> HList xs -> [String]
eval (Pure a)              xs         = []
eval (Free (Input k))      (x ::: xs) = eval (k x) xs
eval (Free (Output s nxt)) xs         = s : eval nxt xs

addTwice :: Action [Int, Int] ()
addTwice = do
  x <- input
  y <- input
  output (show $ x + y)
```

To make things less confusing for users, I introduced type synonyms with friendlier index schemes: `Action' xs rest a` means that the action reads from `xs` and may be followed by actions containing `rest` reads. `Action` is a type synonym equivalent to the one appearing in the thread question.

We can implement a variety of DSL-s with this approach. The reversed typing order gives it a bit of a spin, but we can do the usual indexed monads all the same. Here's the indexed state monad, for example:

```
data IxStateF i j next where
  Put :: j -> next -> IxStateF j i next
  Get :: (i -> next) -> IxStateF i i next

deriving instance Functor (IxStateF i j)
instance IxFunctor IxStateF where imap = fmap

put s = liftf (Put s ())
get   = liftf (Get id)

type IxState i j = IxFree IxStateF j i

evalState :: IxState i o a -> i -> (a, o)
evalState (Pure a)         i = (a, i)
evalState (Free (Get k))   i = evalState (k i) i
evalState (Free (Put s k)) i = evalState k s

test :: IxState Int String ()
test = do
  n <- get
  put (show $ n * 100)
```

Now, I believe this approach is a fair bit more practical than indexing with monoids, because Haskell doesn't have kind classes or first-class type level functions that would make the monoid approach palatable. It would be nice to have a `VerifiedMonoid` class, like in `Idris` or `Agda`, which includes correctness proofs besides the usual methods. That way we could write a `FreeIx` that is generic in the choice of the index monoid, and not restricted to lifted lists or something else.

Comment: Very nice answer and very nice difference lists for types.

Answer (score 5):

Shortly about indexed monads: They are monads indexed by monoids. For comparison default monad:

```
class Monad m where
  return :: a -> m a
  bind :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
  -- or `bind` alternatives:
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
  join :: m (m a) -> m a
```

A monoid is a type equiped with `mempty` - identity element, and `(<>) :: a -> a -> a` binary associative operation. Raised to type-level we could have `Unit` type, and `Plus` associative binary type operation. Note, a list is a free monoid on value level, and `HList` is on a type level.

Now we can define indexed monoid class:

```
class IxMonad m where
  type Unit
  type Plus i j

  return :: a -> m Unit a
  bind :: m i a -> (a -> m j b) -> m (Plus i j) b
  --
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> m i a -> m i b
  join :: m i (m j a) -> m (Plus i j) a
```

You can state monad laws for indexed version. You'll notice that for indexes to align, they must obey monoid laws.

---

With free monad you want equip a `Functor` with `return` and `join` operations. With slightly altererd your definition works:

```
data FreeIx f i a where
  Return :: a -> FreeIx f '[] a -- monoid laws imply we should have `[] as index here!
  Free :: f (FreeIx f k a) -> FreeIx f k a

bind :: Functor f => FreeIx f i a -> (a -> FreeIx f j b) -> FreeIx f (Append i j) b
bind (Return a) f = f a
bind (Free x) f   = Free (fmap (flip bind f) x)
```

---

I have to admit, I'm not 100% sure how `Free` constructor indexes are justified, but they seem to work. If we consider the function `wrap :: f (m a) -> m a` of `MonadFree` class with a law:

```
wrap (fmap f x) ≡ wrap (fmap return x) >>= f
```

and a comment about `Free` in `free` package

> In practice, you can just view a `Free f` a as many layers of `f` wrapped around values of type `a`, where `(>>=)` performs substitution and grafts new layers of `f` in for each of the free variables.

then the idea is that *wrapping values doesn't affect the index*.

---

Yet, you want to *lift* any `f` value to an arbitrary indexed monadic value. This is a very reasonable requirement. But the only valid definition forces lifted value to have `'[]` - `Unit` or `mempty` index:

```
liftF :: Functor f => f a -> FreeIx f '[] a
liftF = Free . fmap Return
```

If you try to change `Return` definition to `:: a -> FreeIx f k a` (`k`, not `[]` -- pure value could have an arbitrary index), then `bind` definition won't type check.

---

I'm not sure if you can make the free indexed monad work with small corrections only. One idea is to lift an arbitrary monad into an indexed monad:

```
data FreeIx m i a where
  FreeIx :: m a -> FreeIx m k a

liftF :: Proxy i -> f a -> FreeIx f i a
liftF _ = FreeIx

returnIx :: Monad m => a -> FreeIx m i a
returnIx = FreeIx . return

bind :: Monad m => FreeIx m i a -> (a -> FreeIx m j b) -> FreeIx m (Append i j) b
bind (FreeIx x) f = FreeIx $ x >>= (\x' -> case f x' of
                                             FreeIx y -> y)
```

This approach feels a bit like cheating, as we could always re-index the value.

---

Another approach is to *remind* `Functor` it's a indexed functor, or start right away with indexed functor as in [Cirdec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27682570/1308058).

Comment: I have incorporated these ideas into a [comprehensive answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27682570/414413) where the `Free` constructor indexes are justified and it's impossible to cheat be re-indexing a value.

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to sacrifice the implicit ordering and use explicit accessors instead, your `Action '[Int, Int]` could be implemented using `ReaderT (HList '[Int, Int])`. If you use an existing library like `vinyl` that provides lenses, you could write something like this:

```
-- Implemented with pseudo-vinyl
-- X and Y are Int fields, with accessors xField and yField
addTwo :: ReaderT (PlainRec '[X, Y]) Output ()
addTwo = do
  x <- view (rGet xField)
  y <- view (rGet yField)
  lift . output $ show (x + y) -- output :: String -> Output ()
```

Type safety is enforced by constraint propagation: `rGet xField` introduces a requirement that `X` be a member of the record.

For a simpler illustration without the type-level machinery, compare:

```
addTwo :: ReaderT (Int, Int) IO ()
addTwo = do
  x <- view _1
  y <- view _2
  lift . putStrLn $ show (x + y)
```

We lose the ordering property, which is significant loss, particularly if the ordering is meaningful, e.g. represents the order of user interaction.

Furthermore, we now *have* to use `runReaderT` (~ `eval`). We can't, say, interleave user input with output.

Answer (score 3):

> EDIT: I have posted a more general [alternative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676294/working-out-the-details-of-a-type-indexed-free-monad/27695354#27695354). I leave
>   this answer here for now since it may be an useful example for
>   constructing the target monad by hand.

My solution does what OP asked for (though it involves manual monad instance writing, so there's room for refinement certainly).

The [`effect-monad`](https://github.com/dorchard/effect-monad/tree/master/examples) package (which OP mentioned) already contains an effect that handles reading from a `HList`. It's called [`ReadOnceReader`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/effect-monad-0.6.1/docs/Control-Effect-ReadOnceReader.html). However, we also need  a `Writer` effect for `Output`, and it seems to me that the library doesn't let us combine these two.

We can still take the idea of `ReadOnceReader` and manually write an AST for the desired language. The AST should be an indexed monad, of course. It would be neat if we could also do this through an indexed free monad or operational monad. I haven't had success with free monads thus far. I might update my answer after I looked at operational monads.

Preliminaries:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    RebindableSyntax, DataKinds, ScopedTypeVariables,
    GADTs, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators,
    PolyKinds, StandaloneDeriving, DeriveFunctor #-}

import Prelude hiding (Monad(..))

data HList (xs :: [*]) where
  Nil  :: HList '[]
  (:>) :: x -> HList xs -> HList (x ': xs)
infixr 5 :>                     

type family (++) (xs :: [*]) (ys :: [*]) where
  '[] ++ ys = ys
  (x ': xs) ++ ys = x ': (xs ++ ys)
```

Indexed monads must provide a way to combine (`Plus`) indices, with identity (`Unit`). In short, indices should be monoids.

```
class IxMonad (m :: k -> * -> *) where
  type Unit m :: k
  type Plus m (i :: k) (j :: k) :: k
  return :: a -> m (Unit m) a
  (>>=)  :: m i a -> (a -> m j b) -> m (Plus m i j) b
  fail   :: m i a
```

The type of `Input` is of interest here: we prepend the input type to the resulting index of the next computation:

```
data Action i a where
  Return :: a -> Action '[] a
  Input  :: (x -> Action xs a) -> Action (x ': xs) a
  Output :: String -> Action i a -> Action i a
deriving instance Functor (Action i)
```

The `IxMonad` instance and the smart constructors are fully standard, and the `eval` function is also implemented straightforwardly.

```
instance IxMonad Action where
  type Unit Action = '[]
  type Plus Action i j = i ++ j
  return = Return
  Return a     >>= f = f a
  Input k      >>= f = Input ((>>= f) . k)
  Output s nxt >>= f = Output s (nxt >>= f)
  fail = undefined

input :: Action '[a] a
input = Input Return

output :: String -> Action '[] ()
output s = Output s (Return ())

eval :: Action xs a -> HList xs -> [String]
eval (Return a)     xs        = []
eval (Input k)      (x :> xs) = eval (k x) xs
eval (Output s nxt) xs        = s : eval nxt xs
```

Now everything works as desired:

```
concat' :: Action '[String, String] ()
concat' = do
  (x :: String) <- input
  (y :: String) <- input 
  output $ x ++ " " ++ y

main = print $ eval concat' ("a" :> "b" :> Nil)
-- prints ["a b"]
```

Comment: `Action i a` works out to be the same as `FreeIx ActionF i a` in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27682570/414413), but is much simpler because you never need to reason about type list appending in general for `Free` and `>>=`. The `IxMonad` instance for `FreeIx` in my answer is more general and doesn't require 
"manual monad instance writing", but comes at the cost of more up-front complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I have a working implementation of an indexed free monad on github from a few years back:

https://github.com/ekmett/indexed/blob/master/src/Indexed/Monad/Free.hs

It uses the form of indexed monad proposed by Conor McBride in [Kleisli Arrows of Outrageous Fortune](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/Kleisli.pdf), and that can be adapted to provide a 2-index free monad in the style of Bob Atkey in the manner described in the paper as well.